# A different kind of integral, the continued product

Tags: calculus, integration

### Definition

I want to define something called *continued product*, which is the analog of continued sum $\int$ but for product.

We will "upgrade" all the elementary operations by $1$, which means sums will become products, and products will become powers.

Let's denote the continued product of a function $f$ like this:

$${}^\Pi\hspace{-3mm} \int f(x)^{\mathrm dx}.$$

We will define it analogically of Riemann sums.

Indeed, we already have

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm dx =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^n f\left(\frac kn\right),$$

so we will say that

> $${}^\Pi\hspace{-3mm} \int_0^1 f(x)^{\mathrm dx} :=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \prod_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac kn\right)\right)^{1/n}.$$

---

### Examples

- For instance, let's compute

$${}^\Pi\hspace{-3mm} \int_0^1 x^{\mathrm dx}.$$

We have

$$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \frac kn\right)^{1/n}=\left(\frac {n!}{n^n}\right)^{1/n}=\frac 1n (n!)^{1/n}.$$

Using Stirling formula, we get:

$$\left(\prod_{k=1}^n \frac kn\right)^{1/n}\sim\frac 1n\left(\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n\right)^{1/n}=\pi^{1/n}(2n)^{1/(2n)}\frac 1e\sim \frac 1e.$$

So

$${}^\Pi\hspace{-3mm} \int_0^1 x^{\mathrm dx}=\frac 1e.$$

- We could also show that

$${}^\Pi\hspace{-3mm} \int_0^1 \exp(x)^{\mathrm dx}=\sqrt e.$$

---

### Questions

- Is there an analog to the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute those kind of integrals quicker ?
- Does this integral have a geometric meaning ?
- What would be some possible applications of this kind of integral ?
- A comment says that is it only $\exp\int \log f$. I don't understand why, regarding to the first example.

Comment: This is nothing but $$\exp \left( \int_0^1 \log f (x) dx \right)$$

Comment: Also, you are missing a $k$ in the formula with the yellow background.

Comment: Thanks @vincent, I edited. I don't get why it is $\exp(\int \log)$ though...

Comment: have a look at this interesting post <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260777/>

Comment: Take your definition for your continued product and take the natural log of both sides.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral

Comment: That is all very useful, thanks ! Should I delete or should i leave this post ?